# how to make an arc diagram of varying radius in R?

Tags: r, graph, arc-diagram

There are multiple R packages for arc diagram such as ggraph or arcdiagram, but if there're more than one connection of different nature, it will show as overlapping arcs of the same radius connecting the same origin and destination. Is it possible to have arc of different radius representing different categories? Something like in this rough graph? Thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `ggplot2` for that. Let the ending points be defined in `df` as

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x1 = 2, x2 = 3, y1 = 21, y2 = 15)
```

Then we use `geom_curve`. It seems that we cannot use the `curvature` parameter as an aesthetic, but `lapply` allows to deal with that:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x1, y = y1, xend = x2, yend = y2)) + 
  lapply(-5:5 / 10, function(cu) geom_curve(curvature = cu)) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

As to get multiple symmetric arcs I use various values of `curvature` defined as

> A numeric value giving the amount of curvature. Negative values
>   produce left-hand curves, positive values produce right-hand curves,
>   and zero produces a straight line.

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to only change `cu` if the curves overlap, i.e. if the data rows are duplicated, if not then keep `cu` as default. For example this data: `df <- data.frame(x1 = c(2, 2, 1), x2 = c(3, 3, 4), y1 = 0, y2 = 0)`

Comment: @zx8754, the problem is that one `geom_curve` gives one arc for each data row. I think you need to start with `ggplot() +` and then keep adding arcs, like in `ggplot() + geom_curve(aes(x=1 ,y=2, xend = 3, yend = 0), curvature = 0.4) + geom_curve(aes(x=1 ,y=2, xend = 4, yend = 0), curvature = 0.2)` and so on. You may again use `lapply`, even a `for` loop to build some list `l` that will contain all the arcs, and also `duplicated(df)` is going to be useful to make things shorter.

Comment: Thank you, Ideally you should be able to pass cu as aes.

Comment: btw is there a way to add text label to the middle of each arc?

Comment: @santoku, I don't think there is a function to achieve that very easily. I think you need `geom_text` and then use some math to compute the coordinates for a given `curvature` value. 1) it seems that when `curvature = +-1`, we get a circle, 2) the gaps between the arcs in the middle seem to be proportional to the differences between `curvature` values. That should allow to calculate the middle of each arc. If you post it as a new question I will try to write an answer.

Comment: @santoku, actually it's more difficult than that. The curves are not at the same place all the time; be resizing the plot their position changes..

Comment: @Julius thanks, I realized the same too, as the curvatures are kinda independent from the coordinates